# java script mask problems

Tags: javascript, jquery

In js library use where .bind("focus.mask") and .bind("blur.mask") function which do blur and focus.

js library:

```
(function(a){var b=(a.browser.msie?"paste":"input")+".mask",c=window.orientation!=undefined;a.mask={definitions:{9:"[0-9]",a:"[A-Za-z]","*":"[A-Za-z0-9]"},dataName:"rawMaskFn"},a.fn.extend({caret:function(a,b){if(this.length!=0){if(typeof a=="number"){b=typeof b=="number"?b:a;return this.each(function(){if(this.setSelectionRange)this.setSelectionRange(a,b);else if(this.createTextRange){var c=this.createTextRange();c.collapse(!0),c.moveEnd("character",b),c.moveStart("character",a),c.select()}})}if(this[0].setSelectionRange)a=this[0].selectionStart,b=this[0].selectionEnd;else if(document.selection&&document.selection.createRange){var c=document.selection.createRange();a=0-c.duplicate().moveStart("character",-1e5),b=a+c.text.length}return{begin:a,end:b}}},unmask:function(){return this.trigger("unmask")},mask:function(d,e){if(!d&&this.length>0){var f=a(this[0]);return f.data(a.mask.dataName)()}e=a.extend({placeholder:"_",completed:null},e);var g=a.mask.definitions,h=[],i=d.length,j=null,k=d.length;a.each(d.split(""),function(a,b){b=="?"?(k--,i=a):g[b]?(h.push(new RegExp(g[b])),j==null&&(j=h.length-1)):h.push(null)});return this.trigger("unmask").each(function(){function v(a){var b=f.val(),c=-1;for(var d=0,g=0;d<k;d++)if(h[d]){l[d]=e.placeholder;while(g++<b.length){var m=b.charAt(g-1);if(h[d].test(m)){l[d]=m,c=d;break}}if(g>b.length)break}else l[d]==b.charAt(g)&&d!=i&&(g++,c=d);if(!a&&c+1<i)f.val(""),t(0,k);else if(a||c+1>=i)u(),a||f.val(f.val().substring(0,c+1));return i?d:j}function u(){return f.val(l.join("")).val()}function t(a,b){for(var c=a;c<b&&c<k;c++)h[c]&&(l[c]=e.placeholder)}function s(a){var b=a.which,c=f.caret();if(a.ctrlKey||a.altKey||a.metaKey||b<32)return!0;if(b){c.end-c.begin!=0&&(t(c.begin,c.end),p(c.begin,c.end-1));var d=n(c.begin-1);if(d<k){var g=String.fromCharCode(b);if(h[d].test(g)){q(d),l[d]=g,u();var i=n(d);f.caret(i),e.completed&&i>=k&&e.completed.call(f)}}return!1}}function r(a){var b=a.which;if(b==8||b==46||c&&b==127){var d=f.caret(),e=d.begin,g=d.end;g-e==0&&(e=b!=46?o(e):g=n(e-1),g=b==46?n(g):g),t(e,g),p(e,g-1);return!1}if(b==27){f.val(m),f.caret(0,v());return!1}}function q(a){for(var b=a,c=e.placeholder;b<k;b++)if(h[b]){var d=n(b),f=l[b];l[b]=c;if(d<k&&h[d].test(f))c=f;else break}}function p(a,b){if(!(a<0)){for(var c=a,d=n(b);c<k;c++)if(h[c]){if(d<k&&h[c].test(l[d]))l[c]=l[d],l[d]=e.placeholder;else break;d=n(d)}u(),f.caret(Math.max(j,a))}}function o(a){while(--a>=0&&!h[a]);return a}function n(a){while(++a<=k&&!h[a]);return a}var f=a(this),l=a.map(d.split(""),function(a,b){if(a!="?")return g[a]?e.placeholder:a}),m=f.val();f.data(a.mask.dataName,function(){return a.map(l,function(a,b){return h[b]&&a!=e.placeholder?a:null}).join("")}),f.attr("readonly")||f.one("unmask",function(){f.unbind(".mask").removeData(a.mask.dataName)}).bind("focus.mask",function(){m=f.val();var b=v();u();var c=function(){b==d.length?f.caret(0,b):f.caret(b)};(a.browser.msie?c:function(){setTimeout(c,0)})()}).bind("blur.mask",function(){v(),f.val()!=m&&f.change()}).bind("keydown.mask",r).bind("keypress.mask",s).bind(b,function(){setTimeout(function(){f.caret(v(!0))},0)}),v()})}})})(jQuery);
```

In my js file I want to unbind this .bind(focus.mask) and .bind(blur.mask) function ?

My Js:

```
function applyInputMasks() {
    var $form.bind("blur.mask",function(){v(),f.val()!=m&&f.change()}) = $('form');

    if ($form.size()) {
        // added try catch so that if input field not found then it wont give an error
        try{
            //$form.find('input:not([skip-masks])[name*=cpf]').mask("999.999.999-99");
            //$form.find('input:not([skip-masks])[name*=document]').mask("999.999.999-99");
            $form.find('input:not([skip-masks])[name*=date]').mask("99/99/9999");
            $form.find('input:not([skip-masks])[name*=postalCode]').mask("999999");
            //$form.find('input:not([skip-masks])[name*=phone]').mask("999999999999");

            // Postal code
            var $postalCode = $form.find('input:not([skip-masks])[name*=postalCode]');

            if ($postalCode.attr('skip-resolve-postalcode')) {
                $postalCode.mask("999999");
            } else {
                $postalCode.mask("999999");
                $postalCode.mask("999999", {completed: resolvePostalCode});
            }

            // override the value AFTER applying the mask
            var valueToOverride = $postalCode.attr('override-value');
            if (valueToOverride) {
                $postalCode.val(valueToOverride);
            }
        } catch (e) {}
    }

    BRAPRINT.util.log('Masks applied!');
}
```

In my form where i use this mask function when I enter 6 digit postal code in box in submit form then city is automatically update If i providing incomplete pin code and clicking outside Postal Box in form data is cleared because in library use .bind("focus.mask") and .bind("blur.mask").

I read this tutorial:
http://view.jqueryui.com/mask/tests/visual/mask/mask.html

where say if .bind() convert to .unbind() then incomplete enter postal code in form not cleared after clicking out of the postal code input box.

after read this functionality I was try this in my js file where postal code :

```
$form.find('input:not([skip-masks])[name*=postalCode]').unbind("focus.mask");
$form.find('input:not([skip-masks])[name*=postalCode]').unbind("blur.mask");
```

and after this I was clearing all cache but this is not working.

I want data not cleared if i enter incomplete postal code. it is possible ?

I don't want to change in mask library file because this is not a right way.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than unbind you could try `e.preventDefault` or `return false` as used in this article on CSS tricks which stops event propagation and bubbling.

http://css-tricks.com/return-false-and-prevent-default/